# Manually Drawing Curves on R like Paint

Tags: r, user-interface

I was trying to allow the user to give a curve as input for some analysis. Is there a package that can be used in this regard? Basically, a GUI like paint wherein the user can draw a simple curve and which would be stored in R as a set of data points or as an equation if its a simple curve.

Thanks
Gopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reading mouse input

Below is a list of sample approaches to first the problem, from the most complex to simplest (IMHO).

1. I would recommend that you have a look at the
   [**`qtpaint`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qtpaint/vignettes/intro.pdf)
   package.
2. Less laborious solution may involve looking at the way *[interactive
   plots](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html)* in **Shiny** are handled. Using the `click` option would
   enable you to get the mouse cursor position. Together with the Shiny
   framework this would provide a convenient wrapper to get mouse input
   from a user.
3. Finally, third approach could rely on making use of the [**`locator`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/locator.html) function available in the `graphics` package. Depending on what you intend to do, this may be the simplest solution as you could then use read values to inform generation of your graphic.

## Generating graphics

Assuming that you got your values via the `locator` functionality you could attempt to draw your line using [**`segments`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html). It would be a little fiddly as you would have to translate your coordinates to some placement of the dot in your desired chart but this wouldn't computationally too taxing, just a matter of bring mouse pointer values to some `x/y` values on the chart.

---

*If you care to update your post with a sample code and reproducible attempts of your previous work, I bet the question will receive more replies. You may find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) on making a reproducible example in **R** helpful.*

Comment: Ah thank you very much. The locator function is exactly what  I was looking for. I made a blank plot and make user select points after which the locator will save the x,y values of the points and also draw the lines between them with type="l" argument.